# What S3 IAM permissions are needed to write a parquet file with Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, devops, amazon-iam, parquet

When Spark writes out parquet files to S3, what actions does it need to do? I'm asking to figure out the set of minimal S3 permissions (aka IAM actions) I should give to my IAM role.

There are two types of situation - I would like to know the necessary permissions for each:

- `df.write.parquet(s3_path)`
- `df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(s3_path)`

I have a big list of permissions that I know to be sufficient, but I don't know which ones are necessary, and I'm hoping somebody knowledgeable on the topic can save me the tedious trial and error.

I tried searching AWS docs, but couldn't find the proverbial needle in the haystack.

Answer (score 1):

IF you are going through the S3A connector, (not the EMR one), then it can be worked out through the org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.delegation.AWSPolicyProvider API, which exists to dynamically ask the current version what policies it needs.

You can use it from your scala code, or you can use the command line entry point in [my cloudstore jar](https://github.com/steveloughran/cloudstore) to ask for one to be dynamically generated.

```
> bin/hadoop jar cloudstore-1.0.jar iampolicy s3a://example-bucket/

{
  "Version" : "2012-10-17",
  "Statement" : [ {
    "Sid" : "7",
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Action" : [ "s3:GetBucketLocation", "s3:ListBucket*" ],
    "Resource" : "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket"
  }, {
    "Sid" : "8",
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Action" : [ "s3:Get*", "s3:PutObject", "s3:PutObjectAcl", "s3:DeleteObject", "s3:AbortMultipartUpload" ],
    "Resource" : "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*"
  }, {
    "Sid" : "1",
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Action" : "kms:*",
    "Resource" : "*"
  } ]
}
```

The first two policies are for R/W access. the KMS one is to encrypt/decrypt data using SSE-KMS. if you aren't doing that, skip it.

1. It is nominally possible to use a subset of the Get* permissions, but the generated policy doesn't do that.
2. If you want to know *why* permissions are needed, the source is all there, look at the different request objects created and POSTed and then see where those operations are called. Open Source exists to answer these questions to a level of detail and correctness which Stack Overflow can't.
3. yes, you do need permissions all the way up the bucket. You can try restricting access, but it is then your problem when things break.
4. GetBucketLocation can probably be disabled but you'd have to experiment with turning off bucket existence probems.