# AWS S3 AccessDeniedException: listMultipartUploads with Magic Committer

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, spark-streaming

So I am trying to use magic committer in my spark job to upload the file in AWS S3 directly. I have been doing the same by mentioning below in spark configuration.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .config("spark.master", "local[*]")
      .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.name", "magic")
      .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.all.committer.magic.enabled", true)
      .getOrCreate
```

Once this is done while writing data to S3 I am getting **AccessDeniedException** stating **listMultipartUploads** access is not available.

```
listMultipartUploads on test/xxxx/xxxxx com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: HJDADSZ7ESJBKD0Z; S3 Extended Request ID: K4AXY=; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: Ob0K4AXY=:AccessDenied
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:249)
```

So I checked the IAM role provided for the bucket I can see the access provided still getting the error not sure what is the issue ?
The role defined as below

```
{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "s3:Get*",
          "s3:List*",
          "s3:PutObject",
          "s3:DeleteObject",
          "s3:ListMultipartUploads",
          "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
          "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
          "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
        ],
        "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:s3:::artifacts/test",
          "arn:aws:s3:::artifacts/test/*",
          
        ]
      }
```

What am I missing here ??? how can I tackle this issue, I have done some searching but got nothing, any pointers in this direction will be great and helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions needed should be as can be extracted from the s3a connector from the process and example of [What S3 IAM permissions are needed to write a parquet file with Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75559892/what-s3-iam-permissions-are-needed-to-write-a-parquet-file-with-spark/75583316#75583316)

1. you may need it to scope it the entire bucket; subdirs and the s3a connector don't work that well.
2. in particular, all the Bucket* operations are called as a POST against the bucket, not against things underneath. That may be a factor.
3. hadoop 3.3.2+ is ok with the listing failing during cleanup, see HADOOP-17547. Therefore: upgrade

Comment: Thanks @stevel for your inputs
1- Scoping to entire bucket is not possible, because the bucket path is formed dynamically based on input and partitions
2- Is there a way by which I can ignore the listing failing in hadoop 3.3.1 version as upgrading is not possible right away. 

Any other way or pointers which could help looking at the constraints

Comment: on hadoop 3.3.2+ you an turn off the cleanup, see https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/committers.html#Concurrent_Jobs_writing_to_the_same_destination  . this is not available on older releases, and it may still fail in interesting ways if you don't have full access. as is usual in open source, don't expect fixes for that except in patches you supply yourself